# PHP 5.2.17 and 5.3.5 Bitwise operators inconsistency

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

So I'm using bitwise `or` and `and` in quite a few places in my hash generator.

The issue is that when I do the bitwise or of `2.0157279968262` and `8657485824`

5.2.17 gives me `8657485826` (production server)
5.3.5 gives me `67551234` (my development server)

This is causing huge differences in the final output:

Final output:
5.2.17: `8ffffffffffffff0000fe00`
5.3.5: `8b86c9257`

Can anyone tell me what is causing this discrepancy and how I can get 5.2.17 to return what 5.3.5 does?

Comment: 32-bit and 64-bit versions of PHP?

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by PHP and not by OS/hardware differences of prod. and dev. environments?

Comment: It isn't only the PHP version, but also the underlying architecture.  Is PHP compiled for 32 or 64 bit?  What about the underlying operating system?

Comment: Use BCMath and for bitwise functionality, check the comments here: http://140.124.30.175/ccteducation/chchting/aiahtm/computer/phphelp/ref.bc.php.htm

Comment: Ah!! My devenv is Win32, the production server is Linux64. So that's what causes the problem? Because I ported the hash generator to java and it works perfectly.

Comment: @GordonM, wouldn't a 64bit system affect a java class in the same way?